# Analytics and no detection of Top Keywords

Tags: google-analytics, keywords, not-provided

We have being online for 5 years and I always noticed that in Analytics we've always get no keywords in the Top Keywords section of Google Analytics.

We use the no provided filter:

[image]

and this is what we have in the Top Keywords list:

[image]

Is there any I can do to get real keywords??

My Webmaster Tool Console is connected and everything seems to be ... normal... I guess

Comment: You fell for that "unlock your not-provided" BS article.    Google doesn't send keyword data in the referrer anymore.   There is no way to generate it.

Comment: Yes Harpreet Munjal is right, but, on queries section you get the queries used by users to get your website not the keywords Google is tracking from your website. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get organic search keywords, you'll need to use Google search console.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/search-analytics?hl=en&siteUrl=

Google Analytics isn't able to receive the keywords from Google search (in most cases). This is because Google is sending traffic from a https:// address and https does not pass previous page data so the Analytics script can't process the search term.

It would be nice if Search Console would work alongside Analytics by providing Analytics the search term data, but at this time it does not seem like that is currently possible and so Search Console is the place to go to see which keywords were used to drive traffic to your site.

Answer (score 1):

you cant check keywords a GA without Connecting Google Console With Analytics. 
You can connect both on Admin Page area of Google Analytics (Gear symbol).

But as you connected both then you can check keywords on-
ACQUISITION >  Search Console > Queries

Hope it helps you.